# parse output in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, grep

My file looks like

```
    //
 [297]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0.0578754,(((23:0.0386924,((((26:0.0160606,22:0.0160606):0.00378,(19:0.0160596,16:0.0160596):0.00378096):0.00242531,12:0.0222659):0.0146336,((29:0.0160393,(17:0.00712055,14:0.00712055):0.00891871):0.0195068,11:0.0355461):0.00135346):0.00179282):0.0468499,4:0.0855423):0.0451632,((25:0.059669,(30:0.0155625,13:0.0155625):0.0441064):0.0223692,(3:0.0288957,1:0.0288957):0.0531425):0.0486673):0.062317):0.60861,((((((62:0.00660739,58:0.00660739):0.011345,(70:0.00496959,54:0.00496959):0.0129828):0.0065665,((68:0.00291155,53:0.00291155):0.0178013,(66:0.0163583,((65:0.0045002,(69:0.00305355,59:0.00305355):0.00144664):0.000757378,(61:0.00311373,52:0.00311373):0.00214385):0.0111007):0.00435459):0.003806):0.123648,(76:0.0395418,(40:0.00641035,34:0.00641035):0.0331314):0.108625):0.0327298,((((46:0.00103749,42:0.00103749):0.0373456,(48:0.0259862,41:0.0259862):0.0123969):0.00173179,(47:0.0275497,39:0.0275497):0.0125652):0.106275,((((44:0.00708562,36:0.00708562):0.0773928,(37:0.025,27:0.025):0.0594785):0.00501024,18:0.0894887):0.0248315,(15:0.0649576,6:0.0649576):0.0493626):0.0320701):0.0345064):0.0680223,((((80:0.0173948,73:0.0173948):0.0162433,(67:0.0129751,((63:0.00435012,57:0.00435012):0.00727273,(60:0.00848091,(64:0.00386096,((56:0.00203231,55:0.00203231):0.00103,51:0.0030623):0.000798654):0.00461996):0.00314194):0.00135223):0.0206631):0.0296773,(33:0.0415374,((75:0.0372575,(45:0.0371022,38:0.0371022):0.000155282):0.0029007,((43:0.0101608,32:0.0101608):0.0242563,31:0.0344171):0.00574108):0.00137926):0.021778):0.147776,((((74:0.0336172,((79:0.0258073,(77:0.0203659,(78:0.00390563,72:0.00390563):0.0164602):0.00544144):0.00767555,49:0.0334829):0.000134364):0.0132633,(35:0.0137148,24:0.0137148):0.0331656):0.0721567,(10:0.0147938,8:0.0147938):0.104243):0.0343567,((71:0.0427659,50:0.0427659):0.0221428,(9:0.0467372,2:0.0467372):0.0181715):0.0884852):0.0576977):0.0378275):0.552713);
    [2271]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0.0578754,(((23:0.0386924,((((26:0.0160606,22:0.0160606):0.00378,(19:0.0160596,16:0.0160596):0.00378096):0.00242531,12:0.0222659):0.0146336,((29:0.0160393,(17:0.00712055,14:0.00712055):0.00891871):0.0195068,11:0.0355461):0.00135346):0.00179282):0.0468499,4:0.0855423):0.0451632,((25:0.059669,(30:0.0155625,13:0.0155625):0.0441064):0.0223692,(3:0.0288957,1:0.0288957):0.0531425):0.0486673):0.062317):0.60861,((((47:0.0363305,(((62:0.00660739,58:0.00660739):0.011345,(70:0.00496959,54:0.00496959):0.0129828):0.0065665,((68:0.00291155,53:0.00291155):0.0178013,(66:0.0163583,((65:0.0045002,(69:0.00305355,59:0.00305355):0.00144664):0.000757378,(61:0.00311373,52:0.00311373):0.00214385):0.0111007):0.00435459):0.003806):0.0118116):0.111837,(76:0.0395418,(40:0.00641035,34:0.00641035):0.0331314):0.108625):0.0327298,((((46:0.00103749,42:0.00103749):0.0373456,(48:0.0259862,41:0.0259862):0.0123969):0.00173179,39:0.0401149):0.106275,((((44:0.00708562,36:0.00708562):0.0773928,(37:0.025,27:0.025):0.0594785):0.00501024,18:0.0894887):0.0248315,(15:0.0649576,6:0.0649576):0.0493626):0.0320701):0.0345064):0.0680223,((((80:0.0173948,73:0.0173948):0.0162433,(67:0.0129751,((63:0.00435012,57:0.00435012):0.00727273,(60:0.00848091,(64:0.00386096,((56:0.00203231,55:0.00203231):0.00103,51:0.0030623):0.000798654):0.00461996):0.00314194):0.00135223):0.0206631):0.0296773,(33:0.0415374,((75:0.0372575,(45:0.0371022,38:0.0371022):0.000155282):0.0029007,((43:0.0101608,32:0.0101608):0.0242563,31:0.0344171):0.00574108):0.00137926):0.021778):0.147776,((((74:0.0336172,((79:0.0258073,(77:0.0203659,(78:0.00390563,72:0.00390563):0.0164602):0.00544144):0.00767555,49:0.0334829):0.000134364):0.0132633,(35:0.0137148,24:0.0137148):0.0331656):0.0721567,(10:0.0147938,8:0.0147938):0.104243):0.0343567,((71:0.0427659,50:0.0427659):0.0221428,(9:0.0467372,2:0.0467372):0.0181715):0.0884852):0.0576977):0.0378275):0.552713);
    [687]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0.0578754,((4:0.128716,(23:0.0386924,((((26:0.0160606,22:0.0160606):0.00378,(19:0.0160596,16:0.0160596):0.00378096):0.00242531,12:0.0222659):0.0146336,((29:0.0160393,(17:0.00712055,14:0.00712055):0.00891871):0.0195068,11:0.0355461):0.00135346):0.00179282):0.0900232):0.0019898,((25:0.059669,(30:0.0155625,13:0.0155625):0.0441064):0.0223692,(3:0.0288957,1:0.0288957):0.0531425):0.0486673):0.062317):0.60861,((((47:0.0363305,(((62:0.00660739,58:0.00660739):0.011345,(70:0.00496959,54:0.00496959):0.0129828):0.0065665,((68:0.00291155,53:0.00291155):0.0178013,(66:0.0163583,((65:0.0045002,(69:0.00305355,59:0.00305355):0.00144664):0.000757378,(61:0.00311373,52:0.00311373):0.00214385):0.0111007):0.00435459):0.003806):0.0118116):0.111837,(76:0.0395418,(40:0.00641035,34:0.00641035):0.0331314):0.108625):0.0327298,((((46:0.00103749,42:0.00103749):0.0373456,(48:0.0259862,41:0.0259862):0.0123969):0.00173179,39:0.0401149):0.106275,((((44:0.00708562,36:0.00708562):0.0773928,(37:0.025,27:0.025):0.0594785):0.00501024,18:0.0894887):0.0248315,(15:0.0649576,6:0.0649576):0.0493626):0.0320701):0.0345064):0.0680223,((((80:0.0173948,73:0.0173948):0.0162433,(67:0.0129751,((63:0.00435012,57:0.00435012):0.00727273,(60:0.00848091,(64:0.00386096,((56:0.00203231,55:0.00203231):0.00103,51:0.0030623):0.000798654):0.00461996):0.00314194):0.00135223):0.0206631):0.0296773,(33:0.0415374,((75:0.0372575,(45:0.0371022,38:0.0371022):0.000155282):0.0029007,((43:0.0101608,32:0.0101608):0.0242563,31:0.0344171):0.00574108):0.00137926):0.021778):0.147776,((((74:0.0336172,((79:0.0258073,(77:0.0203659,(78:0.00390563,72:0.00390563):0.0164602):0.00544144):0.00767555,49:0.0334829):0.000134364):0.0132633,(35:0.0137148,24:0.0137148):0.0331656):0.0721567,(10:0.0147938,8:0.0147938):0.104243):0.0343567,((71:0.0427659,50:0.0427659):0.0221428,(9:0.0467372,2:0.0467372):0.0181715):0.0884852):0.0576977):0.0378275):0.552713);
    [186]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0.0578754,((4:0.128716,(23:0.0386924,((((26:0.0160606,22:0.0160606):0.00378,(19:0.0160596,16:0.0160596):0.00378096):0.00242531,12:0.0222659):0.0146336,((29:0.0160393,(17:0.00712055,14:0.00712055):0.00891871):0.0195068,11:0.0355461):0.00135346):0.00179282):0.0900232):0.0019898,((25:0.059669,(30:0.0155625,13:0.0155625):0.0441064):0.0223692,(3:0.0288957,1:0.0288957):0.0531425):0.0486673):0.062317):0.60861,((((47:0.0363305,(((62:0.00660739,58:0.00660739):0.011345,(70:0.00496959,54:0.00496959):0.0129828):0.0065665,((68:0.00291155,53:0.00291155):0.0178013,(66:0.0163583,((65:0.0045002,(69:0.00305355,59:0.00305355):0.00144664):0.000757378,(61:0.00311373,52:0.00311373):0.00214385):0.0111007):0.00435459):0.003806):0.0118116):0.111837,(76:0.0395418,(40:0.00641035,34:0.00641035):0.0331314):0.108625):0.0327298,((((44:0.00708562,36:0.00708562):0.0773928,(37:0.025,27:0.025):0.0594785):0.00501024,18:0.0894887):0.0248315,(15:0.0649576,6:0.0649576):0.0493626):0.0665766):0.0680223,((((80:0.0173948,73:0.0173948):0.0162433,(67:0.0129751,((63:0.00435012,57:0.00435012):0.00727273,(60:0.00848091,(64:0.00386096,((56:0.00203231,55:0.00203231):0.00103,51:0.0030623):0.000798654):0.00461996):0.00314194):0.00135223):0.0206631):0.0296773,(33:0.0415374,((75:0.0372575,(45:0.0371022,38:0.0371022):0.000155282):0.0029007,((43:0.0101608,32:0.0101608):0.0242563,31:0.0344171):0.00574108):0.00137926):0.021778):0.147776,((((74:0.0336172,((79:0.0258073,(77:0.0203659,(78:0.00390563,72:0.00390563):0.0164602):0.00544144):0.00767555,49:0.0334829):0.000134364):0.0132633,(35:0.0137148,24:0.0137148):0.0331656):0.0721567,(10:0.0147938,8:0.0147938):0.104243):0.0343567,((((46:0.00103749,42:0.00103749):0.0373456,(48:0.0259862,41:0.0259862):0.0123969):0.00173179,39:0.0401149):0.0339623,((71:0.0427659,50:0.0427659):0.0221428,(9:0.0467372,2:0.0467372):0.0181715):0.00916857):0.0793167):0.0576977):0.0378275):0.552713);
```

So after the first line every line starts with a number in brackets. I would need to grep the number in brackets and output it into a new file (without [) ..how would that be done>

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -Po '(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])' file > new_file
```

`-P` for Perl regexs so it is possible to use:

- `\d` for a digit
- *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead* (`(?<=\[)` and `(?=\])`)

`-o` for *only matching*

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility if your `grep` doesn't support the `-P` option but `awk` is available could be this:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{ if ($2 != "") print $2 }' file > new_file
```

`-F` tells `awk` to accept both `]` and `[` as a field delimiter, `$2` then contains the number you want and is printed.

Comment: It gives me following warning: `escape sequence '\[' treated as plain '['` and it does not print anything. I've always used them in reverse order, and the parser reads it right to avoid an empty character class, like: `awk -F '[][]' '...'`

Comment: I'm not getting the warning with awk version 1.3.3 under bash 4.3.30. But your version is more readable, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: My `bash` is the same that yours, but my `awk` is the `GNU` version: `GNU Awk 4.1.1`. It could make the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In three steps using simple commands:

```
grep -v "//" inputfile |  cut -d"[" -f2  | cut -d"]" -f1
```

In sed can you remove everything outside the []:

```
grep -v "//" inputfile |  sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)].*/\1/'
```